# Game engine flight animations, controlled by contact with floor, not keys

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I have an issue with this file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32354

I would like that fancy jet-pack action that he does to only activate when the foot control leaves the ground, and all the other actions to cease to exist while he is airborne, even if I'm not pressing spacebar.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Your Pasteall Link is **DEAD!!!**

Comment: @x-27 pasteall links die after about 5 months. The problem is still clearly explained and the issue is closed. Thanks. :)

Comment: But you still have a pointless link in your post! (dead links drive me near insane - more insane than I already am)

Comment: @X-27 feel free to remove it and stop complaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calls for **States**!

Basically, States let you setup completely different logic brick behaviours for walk and fly and transition between these conditions.

1. Click on the (+) icon on top of the controllers list to show the all the State slots. Notice how all the logic are on the 1st state right now. We'll change that. We'll assign all the walk logic to the 1st state, and all the flying one to the second.
2. Let's setup a detector to figure out when the robot is off the ground using a ray sensor, and have it transition to the 'Fly' state.
   [image]
3. Finally, let's go to the 'Fly' state and setup the logic bricks so that it will transition back to the walk state.
   [image]

The rest should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I must be having a problem with the ray sensor, my object will not return to original state after it enters state two.